# Tool used to create adaptive music

Tags: tools, music

I'm looking for a tool that I came across a few months ago but can't track down anymore. This tool helped create "adaptive" music, where adaptive music refers to music that changes depending on what the player is doing.

This tool allowed you to define a set of input variables, and then define how the music should move between various segments. For example: Loop over this 60 seconds of music until the player reaches 50% through the level, then continue onto this track, but only once the first track plays through to its end.

I think it was open source, and I *think* it exported the information as JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Sadl we don't support technology recommendations, please read the [help]

Comment: @Bálint I realized this was a somewhat iffy topic when I posted it, but my reading of the help center indicated it would be on topic. It is about a game-specific programming issue ("tools" is listed as on-topic on the help page) and it is not about which technology is better or which technology I should use for my game idea (which were listed in the off topic section on the help page). It has a correct answer (I'm looking for a specific tool that I know exists) and it is not a request for recommendations. Is it still off-topic?

Comment: "Tools" is listed in the help center in the context of "game-specific programming issues," so it's referring to *the development of new game pipeline tools* (eg. "Help me with building my mesh importer"). I don't think this question is off-topic since it's not asking for recommendations, but I think you'll likely get better answers on a site more frequented by sound designers & music professionals. I'm not sure how many we have among our regulars currently.

Comment: I remember the system to do this for the old LucasArts games was called MUSE - checking that out may put you down the right path for the particular tool you are looking for.

Comment: I do think this is off topic for the same reasons as an actual “recommendation” question would be: the structure of the request and the validity of the answers is just as open-ended until the question is “solved.” I do think, however, there may be room to adjust these rules in circumstances like this based on something that they do over at Arqade. I’ll start a meta thread about it.